# XML String formatting

Tags: c#, xml, string

I have the below XML string

```
<config crc="ED00B382">
   <setup crc="D5D63153" name="NEW">
       <master comment="" gui_namewidth="160" gui_valwidth="40" name="MASTER" type="u8">
           <item comment="" name="Name" value="0"/>
       </master>
       <enum comment="" gui_namewidth="160" gui_valwidth="40" name="Name" type="u8">
           <item comment="" name="1" value="0"/>
       </enum>
   </setup>
   <data crc="8E5E4B77" name="NEW"/>
</config>
```

Now, I wanted to remove the initial space character from each line from it. What is the best way of it?
Main problem is that space character can be there in the string inside the data part. so I cannot simply write 
str.replace("  ", ""); as it will also replace any two space character inside <> as well.

Comment: If you're using proper XML tools, that know and understand what XML is, why do you *care* about ignorable space?

Comment: Or you want to write a program for this?

Comment: May you give some more context? Is this xml file recurrently generated, with those spaces, and you want to have it generated without them? If yes, how is it generated? External source you can not control? Your own code? If its generated by your own code, may you supply it? ...

Comment: by "initials space", do you mean the indentation? I don't see any value starting with a space.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (line.StartsWith(" ")) {
    line = test.Remove(0, 1);
}
```

Check if the line start with space first, then remove the first occurrence.

hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
string noSpaces = Regex.Replace(xmlString, @"^\s*", "", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

This will go through each line of your string, find the beginning of that line and replace 0,1, or more whitespace characters with an empty string, therefore removing the whitespace. All other whitespaces are left untouched.